# What does meaning a part of query?

Tags: sql

I get a follow query from teammate.
But i cam understand some part of query.
I think its meaning that output name field from db_user and direct_groups table if name field  is equal dba from direct_groups table. Is that right??

```
Select a.name 
from db_user, table(direct_groups) as t(roles) 
where roles.name = 'dba'
```

Comment: exactly what type of SQL? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: Did you ran this query against any database?

Comment: looks like an oracle table function call

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like valid SQL.  Nothing has the alias "a" therefore it can't select "a.name". It looks like the code is attempting to select all user "names" for the users that have the role = "dba".

Answer (score 0):

The query provided appears to use a "table function" and so I think it is Oracle that is being used

Select a.name 
from db_user, **table(direct_groups)** as t(roles) 
where roles.name = 'dba'

If I adjust the query for syntax I would guess that it is doing this:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM db_user a --<< needs this alias
        CROSS JOIN table(direct_groups('roles')) roles --<< use the alias "roles"
WHERE roles.name = 'dba'
```

It appears to list all user names for every row returned by the "table function" that has a name of 'dba'